# How do you connect an arbitrary list of discrete control inputs to a plant?

Tags: python, drake

I have a numpy array of discrete control inputs to provide my plant (one per fixed `time_step`). How would I hook that array of inputs up to my plant such that the inputs are held for `time_step` time?

If I had a [`Trajectory`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1trajectories_1_1_trajectory.html) I could create a [`TrajectorySource`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1_trajectory_source.html) and hook that up to my plant, but I don't have a `Trajectory` object, just a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track.  As best I can tell, what you're looking for is a [PiecewisePolynomial::FirstOrderHold](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1trajectories_1_1_piecewise_polynomial.html#a6ec39e8128c0da804f03d8fbd17fd843) trajectory (to be fed into the TrajectorySource).

Comment: We also have PiecewisePolynomial::ZeroOrderHold (and many others).  Zero order hold is perhaps more literally "the inputs are held for time_step time".